# SharePoint Task List - System Account updating automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, task-list

I have been noticing this spooky phenomena where the items on my task lists are being updated automatically by the System Account. The fields that are updated are Start and End dates and duration. This happens the next day after a change has been made by a user.

Is there anyway I can stop this from happening? Does anyone know why this happens? I don't have a Workflow running on the list.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any workflow or power automate flow running behind this list?

Comment: No. There aren't any workflows or MS Flow behind this. It is just a normal task list